# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app'

Tags: python, django, module

I am trying to make a custom manager that will run a function from another file in a sibling directory, but this error keeps popping up. I have tried:

1) Adding the module to my PYTHONPATH.
2) Adding **init**.py files. 
3) Appending the module to sys.path.

I am using Python3 and Django.

> - /app
> - --- /managers
> - -------/manager.py  <--- `/*importing code here*/`
> - --- /my_app
> - -------/request.py  <--- `/*code to be imported*/`

None of these have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should work with

```
from .. import my_app
```

or

```
from ..my_app import request
```

(Be careful with a name like `request`, it could conflict the argument `request` used inside the views)